# The meaning of ' in Haskell function name?

Tags: haskell, naming-conventions

What is quote `'` used for?  I have read about curried functions and read two ways of defining the add function - curried and uncurried. The curried version...

```
myadd' :: Int -> Int -> Int
myadd' x y = x + y
```

...but it works equally well without the quote. So what is the point of the `'`?

Comment: Will you mind it renamed to "The meaning of ' in Haskell function name?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apostrophe in identifiers in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673916/apostrophe-in-identifiers-in-haskell)

Answer (score 23):

The quote means nothing to Haskell.  It is just part of the name of that function.

People tend to use this for "internal" functions.  If you have a function that sums a list by using an accumulator argument, your sum function will take two args.  This is ugly, so you make a `sum'` function of two args, and a `sum` function of one arg like `sum list = sum' 0 list`.

Edit, perhaps I should just show the code:

```
sum' s [] = s
sum' s (x:xs) = sum' (s + x) xs

sum xs = sum' 0 xs
```

You do this so that `sum'` is tail-recursive, and so that the "public API" is nice looking.

Comment: `sum'` could also be in `sum`'s `where` clause.

Comment: Beware accidentally calling the main function in your recursive function, i.e. `sum' s (x:xs) = sum (s + x) xs`. The type system would complain here, but if the functions have the same type then it's hard to find.

Comment: It normally refers to a slightly altered version of the original function.

Answer (score 17):

It is often pronounced "prime", so that would be "myadd prime". It is usually used to notate a next step in the computation, or an alternative.

So, you can say

```
add = blah
add' = different blah
```

Or

```
f x = 
  let x' = subcomputation x
  in blah.
```

It just a habit, like using int i as the index in a for loop for Java, C, etc.

Edit: This answer is hopefully more helpful now that I've added all the words, and code formatting. :) I keep on forgetting that this is not a WYSIWYG system!

Answer (score 9):

There's no particular point to the `'` character in this instance; it's just part of the identifier.  In other words, `myadd` and `myadd'` are distinct, *unrelated* functions.

Conventionally though, the `'` is used to denote some logical evaluation relationship.  So, hypothetical function `myadd` and `myadd'` would be related such that `myadd'` could be derived from `myadd`.  This is a convention derived from formal logic and proofs in academia (where Haskell has its roots).  I should underscore that this is *only* a convention, Haskell does not enforce it.

Answer (score 6):

quote ' is just another allowed character in Haskell names. It's often used to define variants of functions, in which case quote is pronounced 'prime'. Specifically, the Haskell libraries use quote-variants to show that the variant is strict. For example: `foldl` is lazy, `foldl'` is strict.

In this case, it looks like the quote is just used to separate the curried and uncurried variants.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, the `'` does not hold any meaning for Haskell itself. It is just a character, like the a letter or a number.

The `'` is used to denote alternative versions of a function (in the case of `foldl` and `foldl'`) or helper functions. Sometimes, you'll even see several `'` on a function name. Adding a `'` to the end of a function name is just much more concise than writing `someFunctionHelper` and `someFunctionStrict`.

The origin of this notation is in mathematics and physics, where, if you have a function `f(x)`, its derivate is often denoted as `f'(x)`.