# Apostrophe in identifiers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coding-style, identifier

I found this code snipped on the internet:

```
digits 0 = [0]
digits n = digits' n []
  where digits' 0 ds = ds
        digits' n ds = let (q,r) = quotRem n 10
                       in digits' q (r:ds)

sumOfDigits = sum . digits
```

Can someone quickly explain what the " ' " sign ( `digits n = digits' n []` ) after the recursive function call is for? I've seen some other code examples in Haskell (tutorials), but im not understandig this one. A quick explanation is appreciated.

Comment: I personally try to avoid using apostrophes in my identifiers because I'm too big a fan of Descriptive And Meaningful Phrases.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The apostrophe is just part of the name. It is a naming convention (idiom) adopted in Haskell.

The convention in Haskell is that, [like in math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29#Use_in_mathematics.2C_statistics.2C_and_science), the apostrophe on a variable name represents a variable that is somehow related, or similar, to a prior variable.

An example:

```
let x  = 1
    x' = x * 2
in x'
```

`x'` is related to `x`, and we indicate that with the apostrophe.

---

You can run this in GHCi, by the way,

```
Prelude> :{ 
Prelude| let x  = 1
Prelude|     x' = x * 2
Prelude| in x'
Prelude| :}
2
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Neither in a .hs file nor directly written into the Interpreter.

Comment: @user504060: Try `let { x = 1; x' = x * 2 } in x'`. (Multiline constructs don't work as is in ghci, and expressions don't go at the top level of a Haskell source file.)

Comment: It's a Haskell expression. I've edited the answer to show how you can evaluate multiline expressions in GHCi.

Comment: +1 for showing how to use layout in ghci.  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 11):

It's just another character allowed in identifiers.  Think of it as another letter.