# Stand alone single quotes in Gofer

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The meaning of ' in Haskell function name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207649/the-meaning-of-in-haskell-function-name)
>   [Apostrophe in identifiers in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673916/apostrophe-in-identifiers-in-haskell)

I'm working my way though [this](http://red.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/monparsing.pdf) and implementing it as best I can in Clojure. While I don't know any Gofer (or Haskell), I am figuring out enough as I go. However, I can't seem to find anywhere that explains what the single quotes and double single quotes after inp are supposed to function as.

```
seq :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (a,b)
p `seq` q = \inp -> [((v,w),inp'') | (v,inp') <- p inp
     , (w,inp'') <- q inp']
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: They don't signify anything, they're part of the names. It's a common motif to name related entities similar, using apostrophes to distinguish them. `inp'` (spoken inp-prime) is the input left over after running the first parser on the original input, `inp''` the remaining input after running the second parser on what's left after the the first. Another way would be calling them `inp_1`, `inp_2` or something like that.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks, no wonder I couldn't find them in a language reference :)

Comment: To quote the Haskell report: "An identifier consists of a letter followed by zero or more letters, digits, underscores, and single quotes."

Comment: Gofer! Wow, that takes me back. Last release 13 years ago, Gofer is a lovely implementation of Haskell 1.2, with support for some nice syntactic extensions. However, you should consider using [a modern Haskell](http://haskell.org/platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copied from Don's answer to a previous question)

---

The apostrophe is just part of the name. It is a naming convention (idiom) adopted in Haskell.

The convention in Haskell is that, like in math, the apostrophe on a variable name represents a variable that is somehow related, or similar, to a prior variable.

An example:

```
let x  = 1
    x' = x * 2
in x'
```

`x'` is related to `x`, and we indicate that with the apostrophe.